# bcp select with STUFF function to .json format

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I have a table with 6 columns and need to convert that output to .json format and send output to .json format to a folder.

I'm testing only with one column. When I execute the select statement I get the correct output;

```
select'[' +STUFF((select ',{'+ '"LocationID":"' +LocationID++'"}'FROM ##TABLE FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'') +']';
```

But when I add this select to bcp I get an error copy direction must be either 'in','out' or 'format'

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(8000)
SET @cmd = 'bcp "select ''['' +STUFF((select '',{''+ ''"LocationID":"'' +LocationID+''"}''FROM ##TABLE FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(''.'',''varchar(MAX)''),1,1,'') +'']''" queryout T:\filename.json -c -t, -T'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Tried different things but  didn't work. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, what is you database engine ? Oracle, SQL Server ?

Answer (score 0):

Your crafted SQL command, nestled inside your created bcp command has a bug here:

FOR XML PATH('')

You seem to be already familiar with the need to use the "double single-quote" to get a single quote in a string, but you just missed a location to do this at.
Your code should be:

FOR XML PATH('''')

NOTE: you should avoid using xp_cmdshell. It introduces severe security risks. xp_cmdshell should be disabled.